# Could not find the correct Provider<CalendarProvider> above this BookingPage Widget

Tags: flutter

so i'm trying to build a page having a calendar and available  time slots, when a day in the calendar is selected the available time slots for that day will be displayed, however i'm having this error that says

```
Could not find the correct Provider<CalendarProvider> above this BookingPage Widget
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    ),
  }
```

consider using `builder` like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
    builder: (context) {
      // No longer throws
      return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    }
  ),
}
```

i tried wrapping my page in the ChangeNotifierProvider , and placed it in the top of my code but still have the same error

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  const Sample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => new CalendarProvider(),
        child: BookingPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the BookingPage() widget

```
class BookingPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CalendarProvider calendarProvider = Provider.of<CalendarProvider>(context, listen: false);
    calendarProvider.fetchAvailableDays(); // Fetch available days from Firestore

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('حجز موعد استشارة'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[500],
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context); // Navigate back to the previous page
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: Color(0x7F008080),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        onTap: (index) => _navigateToScreen(context, index),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'الصفحة الرئيسية',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.message_outlined),
            label: 'الرسائل',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month_outlined),
            label: 'استشاراتي',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_2_outlined),
            label: 'حسابي',
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: Column(
        children: [
          Calendar(),
          Expanded(
            child: Consumer<CalendarProvider>(
              builder: (context, calendarProvider, _) {
                calendarProvider.fetchAvailableDays();
                return TimeSlotsGrid(timeSlots: calendarProvider.availableTimeSlots);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the calendar() widget

```
class Calendar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final calendarProvider = Provider.of<CalendarProvider>(context);
    final selectedDay = calendarProvider.selectedDay;

    return TableCalendar(
       // locale: 'pl_PL',
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(titleTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.teal, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, ) , formatButtonVisible : false,),
      firstDay: DateTime.now(),
      lastDay: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 10)),
      focusedDay: selectedDay,
      calendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(selectedDay, day),
      onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
        calendarProvider.setSelectedDay(selectedDay);
      },

      calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.teal,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Text(
              date.day.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Text(
              date.day.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            ),
          );
        },
         defaultBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          final calendarProvider = Provider.of<CalendarProvider>(context);
          final availableDays = calendarProvider.availableDays;

          bool isAvailable = availableDays.contains(date);

          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: isAvailable ? Colors.white : Colors.transparent,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
            ),
            child: Text(
              date.day.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: isAvailable ? Colors.black : Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```